# Do I have to write the `else` statement when implementing a register in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

In order to implement a register outside a process I use the `when` statement in the following way:

```
registered_sig <= (others => '0') when (RESET = '1') else
                  data_sig when (read_data = '1') and (rising_edge(CLK)) else
                  registered_sig;
```

Is there any difference between this and the same statement without the last else part?

```
registered_sig <= (others => '0') when (RESET = '1') else
                  data_sig when (read_data = '1') and (rising_edge(CLK));
```

Comment: Have you found that most synthesis tools interpret this correctly? I've never done it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended HDL coding style should be used for the used synthesis the
synthesis tool, as noted also by fru1tbat and Brian.

For both Altera this can be found in ["Quartus II Handbook - Recommended HDL
Coding Styles"](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii51007.pdf), and
for Xilinx the information can be found in ["XST User Guide - Registers HDL
Coding Techniques"](http://www.xilinx.com/itp/xilinx10/books/docs/xst/xst.pdf).
Both Altera and Xilinx shows flip-flop code using `process` constructions, but
I was not able to find any description using conditional concurrent signal
assign.

If a conditional concurrent signal assign (using `when`) is used anyway, then
it may be worth looking at the equivalent code for:

```
registered_sig <= (others => '0') when (RESET = '1') else
                  data_sig when (read_data = '1') and (rising_edge(CLK)) else
                  registered_sig;
```

which written as process is:

```
process (RESET, data_sig, read_data, CLK, registered_sig) is
begin
  if RESET = '1' then
    registered_sig <= (others => '0');
  elsif (read_data = '1') and (rising_edge(CLK)) then
    registered_sig <= data_sig;
  else
    registered_sig <= registered_sig;
  end if;
end process;
```

But this does not match the recommended VHDL code for processes used to infer
flip-flops in Altera and Xilinx, since the reassign of data out with
`registered_sig <= registered_sig` is not included when inferring flip-flops
with a process.

So to make the conditional concurrent signal assign match the structure when
using `process`, there should be no `else` part in the `when` if using
conditional concurrent signal assign for inference of flip-flops.

Also, remove the `else` part since the code has the same functionality without,
and removing the `else` part avoids the apparent loop in the concurrent assign with

```
registered_sig <= ... else registered_sig;
```

Minor: It should be `(others => '0')`, not `(others <= '0')`.